# TypeScript object with dynamic but required property type

Tags: typescript

I have the following scenario. I need to create an object with a property that can be one of two possible types (custom classes).

```
export class MyType1 {
   // some properties
}

export class MyType2 {
   // some properties
}

class CustomType = MyType1 | MyType2

class Config {
   propOne: boolean;
   dynamicParam: { [key: string ]: CustomType }
}
```

The *Config* object would be used as provided below:

```
let config: Config = {
   propertyOne: true,
   dynamicParam: {
      key1: {
         // properties from one type
      },
      key2: {
         // properties from another type
      }
   }
}
```

If I specify the type of the property when I define the object, as show below:

```
   key1: <MyType1> {

   }
```

I get intellisense for properties of MyType1 class. If I don't specify the type however, I get intellisense for the properties of both, MyType1 and MyType2 classes (since the type of dynamicParam property is CustomType [union type]).

My question is, is it possible to make required type definition when defining the object, so that when I try to define a property as:

```
   key1: {

   }
```

I get an error that a type must be specified?

Comment: As an aside, it's not a good idea to assign an object literal to a type defined as a  `class`, since `instanceof` will fail for that object literal.   You probably should make those `class` definitions all `interface` definitions instead.

Comment: And `class X = Y | Z` is not valid TypeScript syntax.  You're looking for a type alias: `type X = Y | Z`.

Comment: I will refactor the code as you suggested. I have this mistake in multiple different places. But before that, I really need to dig in deeper into `class`, `interface` and `type` documentation.

Comment: Basically, long story short, if you need only the benefit of type-checking you need to use interfaces. If you need to create new instances and type-checking go with classes. Got it.

Answer (score 3):

Let's fix your code so that it compiles and has some specific properties to see what you mean:

```
interface MyType1 {
  a: string,
  b: number,
  c: boolean
}

interface MyType2 {
  d: string,
  e: number,
  f: boolean
}

type CustomType = MyType1 | MyType2
```

I think maybe you're not happy that the following code compiles without complaint:

```
let customType: CustomType = {
  a: "yes",
  b: 2,
  c: false,
  d: {what: "the"} // no error here
}
```

Even though types in TypeScript are not ["exact types"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) (where values are restricted to only the properties explicitly specified in the type definition), they behave more like exact types when you deal with object literals.  When you assign an object literal to a variable, the literal undergoes [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) which will warn you if it contains any unexpected properties.  For example, the following will be an error:

```
let warnCustomType: CustomType = {
  a: "yes",
  b: 2,
  c: false,
  nope: { what: "the" } // error
  // Object literal may only specify known properties, 
  // and 'nope' does not exist in type 'CustomType'.
}
```

However, for union types like `CustomType`, which are not [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions), the excess property checking does not work on each constituent of the union separately; rather, it works on the whole union.  So you will not be warned about the `d` property above, because `d` is a valid property for at least one of the constituents of the `CustomType` union.  This behavior is considered to be a [bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20863), and might get fixed in a future release of TypeScript.  But I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for it.

Your suggestion to somehow require that the type of an object literal property be asserted by the developer is interesting but I don't think it's possible.  You could come up with a convention, but nothing in the language would force someone to follow it.

Instead, you might be able to get away with explicitly forming something like an exact type for the union in question, and then requiring that the property be that type.  Consider the following type functions using [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types):

```
type AllPossibleKeysOf<U> = U extends any ? keyof U : never;

type Exclusify<U> = [U] extends [infer V] ? V extends any ? (
  V & Partial<Record<Exclude<AllPossibleKeysOf<U>, keyof V>, never>>
) : never : never
```

I won't go into too much detail about how they work, but basically `Exclusify<U>` breakes up a union `U` into its consituents, and forms a new union where each constituent explicitly disallows properties from the other types in the union.

Let's see it in action on `CustomType`:

```
type ExclusiveCustomType = Exclusify<CustomType>;
```

If you inspect that it becomes

```
(MyType1 & Partial<Record<"d" | "e" | "f", never>>) | 
(MyType2 & Partial<Record<"a" | "b" | "c", never>>)
```

which is mostly equivalent to

```
{a: string, b: number, c: boolean, d?: never, e?: never, f?: never} |
{a?: never, b?: never, c?: never, d: string, e: number, f: boolean}
```

Those optional properties of type `never` are essentially unusable and are either absent completely or `undefined` if present.  Now if you try the following:

```
let customType: ExclusiveCustomType = {
  a: "yes",
  b: 2,
  c: false,
  d: {what: "the"} // error
}
```

you get an error on `d` not being a `string | undefined` (since the type of `d` is either `string` if you use the first part of the union, or `undefined` if you use the second part of the union).  If you try to fix it by making it a `string`, you still get an error:

```
let customType: ExclusiveCustomType = {
  a: "yes",
  b: 2,
  c: false,
  d: "nope"
} // error! Types of property 'd' are incompatible.
```

So `ExclusiveCustomType` is more restrictive than `CustomType`.  I don't know if that's the way you want to go, but it's *a* way.  Maybe others will have different ideas.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Your suggestion about _conditional types_ and union breaking into its constituents is the way to go. However, I have just recently started working with TypeScript and all these concepts are above my knowledge are are still confusing to me. I'll need to read a **lot** more.

Answer (score 0):

Since TypeScript has a structural type system, an object literal with all the properties of either `MyType1` or `MyType2` will be accepted.  I'm not aware of any reasonable way to require a type assertion like `<MyType1>`, but if you add a discriminant property somewhere in the type definition, then it will be required in the config.  For example, you could do:

```
export enum MyTypes { 
    TYPE1, TYPE2
}

export class MyType1 {
    kind: MyTypes.TYPE1;
   // some properties
}

export class MyType2 {
    kind: MyTypes.TYPE2;
   // some properties
}

type CustomType = MyType1 | MyType2;

class Config {
   propertyOne: boolean;
   dynamicParam: { [key: string ]: CustomType }
}

let config: Config = {
    propertyOne: true,
    dynamicParam: {
        key1: {
            kind: MyTypes.TYPE2,
            // properties from one type
        },
        key2: {
            kind: MyTypes.TYPE1,
            // properties from another type
        }
    }
};
```